# How to fix flickering when addSliderAccess is true in a jQuery time picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery-ui-timepicker-addon v1.6.3.

I need to allow showing slider control buttons( +, - ).

When I select a date then the slider panel is flickering.

```js
$("#datetime_input_1").datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss"
});
$("#datetime_input_2").datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
  addSliderAccess: true,
  sliderAccessArgs: {
    touchonly: false
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Imports -->
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="parent">
  <div class="form-control" id="datetime_input_1"></div>
  <div class="form-control" id="datetime_input_2"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the [example](https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker) which was provided by owner.

[image]

How to fix this flickering issue?

Comment: It seems [you've already posted an issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/962). While there, you may want to read more into the backlog of issues, [as issue #955 indicates it's abandonware](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/955)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your advice. Could you please provide me alternative time picker which supports milliseconds?